# remove bullets from woocommerce shop lists

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to remove the bullets from the following site:

www.earlsandco.co.uk

on the cart widget on the right hand side of the page.

I have played with the css using list-style-type:none; for all sorts of options under both the themes styles and the woocommerce styles but still can't get rid of the bloody bullet!

Any help much appreciated

Thanks
JD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on

```
.widget ul li
```

You have

```
 background: url("images/marker-1.png") no-repeat scroll 0 14px transparent;
```

Remove this from the CSS, as it's not a list-style, and that's what's causing the bullet image.